# EasyPost Create Webhook returns null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, easypost

I tried to create an easy post webhook using easy post in asp.net core API project. it returns a null value in webhook creations.

i tried this

```html
using EasyPost;
EasyPost.ClientManager.SetCurrent("<YOUR_TEST/PRODUCTION_API_KEY>");

Webhook webhook = Webhook.Create(
    new Dictionary<string, object>() {
        { "url", "https://www.foobar.com" }
    }
);
```

Comment: While it's possible to create webhooks with the client libraries, it's easier to do through the EasyPost Dashboard https://www.easypost.com/account/webhooks-and-events

Comment: Thank you KFunk,
That is easy but, I need to create a webhook in C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have the webhook create method return JSON properly by using the most current version of the [C# client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EasyPost-Official/). This is the code snippet I used:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using EasyPost;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace create_webhook
{
    class createWebhook
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EasyPost.ClientManager.SetCurrent(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EASYPOST_API_KEY"));

            Webhook webhook = Webhook.Create(
                new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                    { "url", "https://www.foobar.com" }
                }
            );
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(webhook, Formatting.Indented));
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```json
{
  "id": "hook_123...",
  "mode": "test",
  "url": "https://www.foobar.com",
  "disabled_at": null
}
```

For reference, the [API docs](https://www.easypost.com/docs/api/csharp#create-a-webhook) related to creating a webhook for C# do not specifically mention to print what is returned which is why in my example I added a print statement.